# SortedList Desc Order

Tags: c#

I am using `SortedList` to arrange `arraylist` records dynamically in sort order by `datecolumn`, but by default it is  sorting in ascending order. I have been trying to get order in descending order but not able to get it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no way to instruct the SortedList to do sorting in descended order. You have to provide your own Comparer like this

```
    class DescendedDateComparer : IComparer<DateTime>
    {
        public int Compare(DateTime x, DateTime y)
        {
            // use the default comparer to do the original comparison for datetimes
            int ascendingResult = Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare(x, y);

            // turn the result around
            return 0 - ascendingResult;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedList<DateTime, string> test = new SortedList<DateTime, string>(new DescendedDateComparer());
    }
```

Comment: Yep you gotta supply your own comparison. It is also worth noting that there is a built in string comparer which can ignore case: StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase

Comment: Thanks for your reference, i have achieved the order in desc

Comment: Isn't it much easier to just swap the order of the parameters rather than subtracting the result from 0? I.e. `Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare(y, x)`?

Answer (score 44):

Swapping y for x should do when comparing

```
class DescComparer<T> : IComparer<T>
{
    public int Compare(T x, T y)
    {
        if(x == null) return -1;
        if(y == null) return 1;
        return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(y, x);
    }
}
```

and then this

```
var list = new SortedList<DateTime, string>(new DescComparer<DateTime>());
```

Comment: This is the best answer. Nice generic solution too!

Comment: You can avoid creating your own class by using built-in Create lambda: `Comparer<DateTime>.Create(((a, b) => b.CompareTo(a)))`

Answer (score 21):

You can just use [Reverse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx)  to sort the SortedList in descending order:

```
var list = new SortedList<DateTime, string>();

list.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 2), "Third");
list.Add(new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), "Second");
list.Add(new DateTime(2010, 1, 1), "FIRST!");
list.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), "Last...");

var desc = list.Reverse();

foreach (var item in desc)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: The author of this question is talking about arranging items in descended order not reading it. Still a valuable answer to include though.

Comment: increasing the runtime complexity with the reverse O(N).

Answer (score 3):

```
Comparer<DateTime>.Create((x, y) => 0 - Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare(x, y));
```

Comment: An equivalent solution has been proposed already, although only as a comment, not as an answer. But still, could you please write some text explaining the code? Also, as pointed out already, one could simply swap arguments (`Compare(b, a)`) instead of subtracting from 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just swap a and b in the Default Comparer, which is accessible through these convenience classes and properties:

```
var desc = Comparer<DateTime>.Create((a, b) => Comparer<DateTime>.Default.Compare(b, a));

var sortedList = new SortedList<DateTime, T>(desc);
```

Comment: It was a nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

while adding the value if we multiply with -1 we can achieve descending order.

Example - Lets say we want to store 10 and 3 but list should be sorted in desc without any extra operation (Reverse, IComparer), we can multiply each no with -1 before adding as key and the original value as value, like I am doing below

```
SortedList<int, int> pairs = new SortedList<int, int>();
pairs.Add(-10, 10);
pairs.Add(-3, 3);
```

Now the list having the items sorted in desc order as 10 will be at the top.

[image]

Comment: Actually this is a good answer but you must use absolute keys