# Get SortedList type after sorting in desc order

Tags: c#, sorting, collections

```
SortedList<string, object> testIds = new SortedList<string, object>();
```

Can I get SortedList type of collection after sort in descending order?
For example :

```
SortedList<string, object> SortedTestIds = testIds.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Key);
```

or some other cases.

Comment: you can use var SortedTestIds = testIds.OrderByDescending(t => t.Key);

Comment: I know about `var`, but in my case I need  SortedList

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815930/sortedlist-desc-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the `var` like

```
var SortedTestIds = testIds.OrderByDescending(t => t.Key);
```

or if you want SortedList then you have to use `IComparer` for your own Comparer.

here you can find it [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815930/sortedlist-desc-order)

Comment: can give me any advice how to create similar comparer to sort SortedList not for key, but for value.